# Google app indexing ios search result

Tags: ios, google-search, google-app-indexing, deeplink

I have implemented Google app indexing sdk in test project and able to deep link from google search result URL to respective page in app. But google search results displayed in normal search result style without app icon like app pack style. Is it because I am testing in a test app? Will search result displayed in app pack style once I submit app in app store then downloaded and installed?

In iOS I am passing itunes id to google app indexing sdk.So My gut feeling is app packs will displayed in google search result only for itunes app not the test app.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App icon will display only for itunes app integrated with google app indexing sdk.